# Optimization with positive definite constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, positive-definite, constraints, semidefinite-programming

Suppose I have a function $f$ that is strictly convex on the positive semidefinite sets. I wonder if it is generally possible to minimize $f$ with positive definite constraints?

$$\text{minimize } f(X)$$
$$\text{subject to } X\succ0$$

Any reference books or ideas or tricks are appreciated!

Comment: Are you particularly asking about the positive definite cone in contrast to optimization over the positive semidefinite cone which is a fairly standard optimization class.

Comment: Correct. Optimize on a positive definite cone. An application can be finding a positive definite covariance matrix that minimize a loss function. Or finding a positive definite precision matrix that minimize a loss function.

Comment: You understand that is typically not well-defined in practice as you won't have any minimizer?

Comment: Yes. However, there may be some tricks to overcome this problem. For example, minimize $x^2$ subject to $x>0$. No minimizer exists. However, if we add a small "barrier" to the objective function, and instead we minimize $x^2 - \epsilon\log x$ subject to $x>0$, then we can have a minimizer that is close to zero. I am looking for reference books, ideas or tricks :)

Comment: Then the question is why you would want to introduce a magic constant in such an involved manner, instead of just introducing it as $\succeq \epsilon I$. Theoretically, you are basically reinventing a classical primal-only interior-point solver.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it would be possible to add more constraints on certain element of $X$ to be zero? For examples, $X_{ij}=0$, where $(i,j)\in\Omega$, and $\Omega$ is given.

Comment: How does that relate to the question? You can add what ever constraint you want. Whether you can solve it (either using available solvers or by develop your own dedicated solver) is another issue.